# Show page load time at top of page using PHP

Tags: php

I am using this code to show PHP Page load times. This code i currently put at the end of my PHP scripts.

How can i put this at the top of the page and still make it work?

```
<?php
$time = microtime();
$time = explode(' ', $time);
$time = $time[1] + $time[0];
$finish = $time;
$total_time = round(($finish - $start), 4);
echo 'Page generated in '.$total_time.' seconds.';
?>
```

Comment: honestly, no one cares how long you say it took to load a page, this was popular several decades ago. but just looks sad now

Comment: i want it for an internal system

Answer (score 0):

You can save your page to a variable and append it to your load time. There are maybe better ways to do it, but this should work:

```
$pagetext = "<html> " . generateTitle() . "" . generateContent() . " ";//etc
$total_time = round(($finish - $start), 4);
$pagetext = $total_time.$pagetext;
echo($pagetext);
```

But this would make the time appear outside the html document. So you could seperate the header and the acutal text:

```
$header = "<html> ";
$pagetext = generateTitle() . " " . generateContent() . " ";//etc
$total_time = round(($finish - $start), 4);
$pagetext = $header .  $total_time .  $pagetext;
echo($pagetext);
```

Comment: And, finally, @user3815283 might use a class to solve a problem :)